what are the best practices around GraphQL mutation responses and errors?
I am a little confused about best practices for mutation responses in GraphQL. The product I am working on adopted the following:
enum MutationStatus {
    SUCCESS
    FAILURE
}

# Response interface per the recommendation described here:
# https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/schema.html#mutation-responses
interface MutationResponse {
    status: MutationStatus!
    message: String
}

This was our first GraphQL project, 5 years ago, so learning was done on-the-fly.
As far as I can tell, we pretty much return SUCCESS or FAILURE and ok or very limited details about the error.
As you can see, this is based on recommendations that are no longer available at the given link. However, poking around that website, I found this page and this other page that talk about using a structure similar to:
interface MutationResponse {
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
}

The problem I have is that I cannot find any example that shows anything but success in the response. So, that structure makes sense for success I guess. But then I ran into issues because mutations are technically not failing (They return an error code, but are considered successful). This is preventing us from using the multiple mutations in a single query capability of GraphQL (because if the first mutation fails, the following mutations should not execute - but they do with our current approach).
Furthermore, still on that same website, in their blog, this post shows examples, without using that structure. It's also a lot of work on our backend as we have to wrap all our mutations with a try/catch block and return the failure message.
What did we do wrong? and where can we find best practices around those mutation responses?

Yeah, don't use a response object to distinguish between success and failure, with only a message - that's what GraphQL errors are for. Response objects are useful if you have additional status information (warnings, statistics, different success messages) about your successful result, other than just the updated/created entity. That is what the mutation payload is about.
